# Selenium TestNG: driver.close() and driver.quit()

Tags: java, selenium

I have written a simple Selenium TestNG script as below but getting an error `java.lang.NullPointerException` at the `@AfterTest` method. Can you please help on this?

```
    public class TestngDemo1    
        {
            public WebDriver driver;
            public String url="https://www.guru99.com/";

            @Test
            public void LaunchURL() throws InterruptedException {         
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/AB28488/Desktop/javawork
        space/TestNGProject/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(); 
                driver.get(url);  
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                String eTitle="Meet Guru99 - Free Training Tutorials & Video for IT Courses";
                String aTitle=driver.getTitle();
                Reporter.log(aTitle);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Assert.assertEquals(aTitle, eTitle);
                Reporter.log("This will print if titles match!",true);
           }

           @BeforeMethod
           public void BeforeMethod() {
               Reporter.log("Before Method");
           }

           @AfterMethod
           public void afterMethod() {
               Reporter.log("After method",true);
           }  

           @AfterTest 
           public void quitDriver() { 
              driver.quit();
           }

      }
```

Comment: public WebDriver driver;  &  WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();  Why are creating two instances of driver .?

Comment: In you before test method add following code driver= new ChromeDriver(); instead of instantiating inside test method

Comment: Convert your class to testng

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your test you define locally visible driver

```
public class TestngDemo1
{
    // This is your "global" driver
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String url="https://www.guru99.com/";

    @Test
    public void LaunchURL() throws InterruptedException
    {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/AB28488/Desktop/javawork
                space/TestNGProject/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        // This is not the same driver you have defined above as a class field        
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void quitDriver()
    {
        // Here you're trying to call method of an object that does not exist.
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Try use this instead:

```
public class TestngDemo1
{
    // This is your "global" driver
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String url="https://www.guru99.com/";

    @Test
    public void LaunchURL() throws InterruptedException
    {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/AB28488/Desktop/javawork
                space/TestNGProject/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void quitDriver()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Can you give me the corrected code please.

Comment: Not sure what would be the proper code since I'm not an expert in TestNG. Lets's elaborate one. First try change "WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();" to "driver= new ChromeDriver();"

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will work for you:

```
    public class TestngDemo1    
        {
           public WebDriver driver;
           public String url="https://www.guru99.com/";

          @Test
          public void LaunchURL() throws InterruptedException 
          {  
            driver.get(url);  
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            String eTitle="Meet Guru99 - Free Training Tutorials & Video for IT Courses";
            String aTitle=driver.getTitle();
            Reporter.log(aTitle);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Assert.assertEquals(aTitle, eTitle);
            Reporter.log("This will print if titles match!",true);
         }

        @BeforeTest
        public void initDriver()
        {        
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/AB28488/Desktop/javawork
space/TestNGProject/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver= new ChromeDriver(); 

         }
         @AfterTest 
         public void quitDriver()
         { 
            driver.quit();
         }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating three classes: GetProperties, BaseTest, and Tests. GetProperties reads config.properties file and returns java.util.Properties with keys and values (url, millis).

BaseTest opens and closes browsers.

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BaseTest extends GetProperties{

    public static FirefoxDriver geckoDriver;
    public static ChromeDriver chromeDriver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void driversInit() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "your/path/geckodriver");
        geckoDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "your/path/chromedriver");
        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void driversQuit() throws Exception {
        geckoDriver.quit();
        chromeDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

Tests runs tests.

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class Tests extends BaseTest{
    @Test
    public void testChromeOpenURL() throws InterruptedException {
        chromeDriver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(millis*10);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFirefoxOpenURL() throws InterruptedException {
        geckoDriver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(millis*10);
    }
}
```